# Adding content on filter to an isotope based site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have created a site using isotope and am having trouble adding items when you click one of the filters.

This is script i am using for the filtering:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // cache container
    var $container = $('#container');
    // initialize isotope
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '.front'
    });   

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('#filters a').click(function() {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

which works perfectly but I am having trouble with adding or unhiding content,

I have attempted to adapt this http://jsfiddle.net/RRgjD/ to my code but I am not great with javascript and keep falling flat on my face.

Below is an example of the html I am using.

```
<li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".identity, .menufilter">&mdash; Brand Identity</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".guidelines, .menufilter">&mdash; Brand Guidelines</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".photography, .menufilter">&mdash; Brand Photography</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter" data-filter=".digital, .menufilter">&mdash; Digital</a></li>


<div class="item cols-1 rows-1 identity">
    <span class="new-wrapper">
        <div class="post-thumb clearfix">
            <a title="Eternal friendship" href="#">
                <img src="images/thumbs/oxford.jpg" alt="brain" width="200" height="133"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><span>
            <h2></h2> 
            <p>
                <p></p>
            </p>
        </span></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Any help or direction would be brilliant. I have also looked into the insert method that comes with isotope but it is well above my head and I'm not even sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This started to filter the .front classes but the filtering of other classes doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

 var $container = $('#container'),
    $checkboxes = $('#filters a');

 $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item'
 });

 $container.isotope({
    filter: '.front'
 });

 $checkboxes.change(function() {
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values
    $checkboxes.click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
    });
    // ['.red', '.blue'] -> '.red, .blue'
    filters = filters.join(', ');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: filters
    }, function($changedItems, instance) {
        instance.$allAtoms.filter('.isotope-hidden').removeClass('is-filtered');
        instance.$filteredAtoms.addClass('is-filtered');
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: ps. the filter: '.front' part of the script was part of the attempt to filter the content I want to appear at first by just hiding everything else. Thanks

Comment: It will help people answer if you create a jsfiddle of your own

Comment: I don't understand where is your problem? When you click on a link it should refilter with the data attribute indicated (BTW, you should use : `$(this).data("filter")` in order to retrieve the data)...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the content with buttons that filter between certain categories which works perfectly but I would also like to filter the content when the user first opens the page so some of the content remains hidden and only appears when the buttons are clicked. Sorry if I don't make sense a lot of this is new to me. I can send a link to the site if you need a reference. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am barking up the wrong tree with this but I was trying to set it so that on the page load $container.isotope({ filter: .front }); so that it loads all the classes specified with .front and then when a button is clicked it executes $container.isotope({ filter: selector }); and filters to .identity .guidelines . photography or .digital depending on what button was clicked. The latter works but the filtering content on pageload to .front classes doesn't.

Comment: When I refresh your jsFiddle, it filters to `.red` automtically. Does this not work for you?

Comment: This is a similar thread with a working solution. But it uses the Isotope non-Jquery (plain-vanilla js) version. Code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22633966/1444464

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `filter` on the classes you want to be shown at startup:

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: '.guidelines, .photography' 
});
```

This example shows two of your categories at startup.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByGAP/)

Other things that can ruin the functionality is messy HTML/CSS (animations, visible/hidden elements etc.)