# Issue with Isotope js filter

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem applying a filter in Isotope js.  All of my content seems to disappear when applying filters.  (Note:  This question is about using Isotope in a plain vanilla JS environment and not Jquery).

I have a series of DIVs

```
<DIV id="thecontainer">
 <DIV class="displaybox catnum1"> div content </DIV>
 <DIV class="displaybox catnum1"> div content </DIV>
 <DIV class="displaybox catnum2"> div content </DIV>
 <DIV class="displaybox catnum2"> div content </DIV>
 <DIV class="displaybox catnum3"> div content </DIV>
</DIV>
```

So I have a simple function to filter by category:

```
function ShowCat(catnumber) {
    var container = document.getElementById('thecontainer');
            var iso = new Isotope(container);
    iso.arrange(
        filter: '.catnum'+catnumber,
        });
 }
```

If I call ShowCat(2), everything seems to work fine.   Only the two DIV's with the 'catnum2' class are visible.  The others disappear.  So far so good...

But if I call ShowCat again (eg:  ShowCat(1); ) instead of re-filtering to show just the 'catnum1' DIV's, all of the DIV's disappear, and I have a blank screen.

I have tried pre-filtering with "*" as my filter type.   I have also tried doing a sortBy "original-order", prior to executing the function again with a new filter request.   But nothing seems to restore the DIV's to their original view.  The function only seems to run once, and all successive calls seem to add new filters onto the first filter request, rather than preforming a new filter request from scratch.

Is there something I need to do prior to running a new filter?   Any clues as to why everything is disappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

If anyone else has a similar issue using Isotope without Jquery, I hope the following function proves useful.    No frameworks (other than Isotope) are necessary.

(This will hide and reveal DIV's as defined in the question).

Call the function with:   cats.showCat(1);

Reset to original (nonfiltered view) with a null argument:   cats.showCat();

```
var Cats = (function(){

function Cats(element) {
    this.element = element;

    this.iso = null;

    this.currentCat = null;


    this.init(); 
};

Cats.prototype.init = function() {
    this.iso = new Isotope(this.element);
};

Cats.prototype.showCat = function(catNumber) {
    if(this.currentCat == catNumber){
        return;
    };

    this.currentCat = catNumber;

    if(catNumber == null){
        this.iso.arrange({
            filter: '*'
        });
    }else{
        this.iso.arrange({
            filter: '.catnum' + catNumber
        });
    };

};


 return Cats;
 })();


var cats = new Cats(document.getElementById('thecontainer'));
```